# There is a problem with TIM2_CH1 on stm32f103c8t6

Tags: c, timer, stm32, pwm

I capture input PWM signal from AURORA9x using 3 timers (TIM4_CH1, TIM3_CH1, TIM2_CH1). All works great except TIM2_CH1. I can't to fix that issue for 3 days. May be some of You came across to this problem.
 Here code for three timers. Configuration for all timers are same, but TIM2 doesn't work

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"
#include "can.h"
#include "main.h"

void TIM4_Config(void);
void TIM3_Config(void);
void TIM2_Config(void);


uint32_t   DataCapture_TIM4=0,
           DataCapture_TIM3=0,
           DataCapture_TIM2=0;
```

Timer Configuration for capturing mode for TIM4_CH1

```
void TIM4_Config(void)
{ 
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef     TIM_Time_user;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef            port;
    TIM_ICInitTypeDef           TIM_ICInit_user;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure2;
// TIM4 clock enable
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
// GPIOB clock enable
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
// TIM4 channel_1 configuration : PB6
port.GPIO_Pin   = GPIO_Pin_6;
port.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
port.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;

GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &port);
// Connect TIM pin to AF2

// Enable the TIM4 global Ymtirrupt
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure2);

// Time base configuration
TIM_Time_user.TIM_Period = PERIOD;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_Prescaler = PRESCALER;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &TIM_Time_user);

//Capture configuration
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_Channel = TIM_Channel_1;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICPolarity = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICSelection = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICFilter = 0x0;

//Inicialize our structure for capture signal
TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM4, &TIM_ICInit_user);
//input trigger
TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM4, TIM_TS_TI1FP1);

  TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);
    // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
   TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM4,TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);

// Enable the TIM4 Counter
TIM4->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

// Enable the CC1 Interrupt request
TIM4->DIER |= TIM_IT_CC1;
}
```

Interrupt handler for TIM4_CH1

```
void TIM4_IRQHandler(void)
{

if (TIM4->SR & TIM_SR_CC1IF )
    {

        DataCapture_TIM4 = TIM4->CCR2;
    }

}
```

Capture mode for TIM3_Ch1

```
void TIM3_Config(void)
{ 

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef     TIM_Time_user;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef            port;
    TIM_ICInitTypeDef           TIM_ICInit_user1;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure1;
// TIM4 clock enable
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, ENABLE);
// GPIOB clock enable
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
// TIM channel1 confikurotion : PA6
port.GPIO_Pin   = GPIO_Pin_6;
port.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;///////////////////////////////
port.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;

GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &port);

// Enable the TIM3 global interrupt
NVIC_InitStructure1.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM3_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure1.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure1.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure1.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure1);
// Time base configuration
TIM_Time_user.TIM_Period = PERIOD;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_Prescaler = PRESCALER;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &TIM_Time_user);
//
TIM_ICInit_user1.TIM_Channel = TIM_Channel_1;
TIM_ICInit_user1.TIM_ICPolarity = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
TIM_ICInit_user1.TIM_ICSelection = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
TIM_ICInit_user1.TIM_ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
TIM_ICInit_user1.TIM_ICFilter = 0x0;
//
TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM3, &TIM_ICInit_user1);
//input trigger
TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM3, TIM_TS_TI1FP1);

  TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM3, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);
    // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
   TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM3,TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
// Enable the TIM3 Counter
TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

// Enable the CC1 Intirrupt Request
TIM3->DIER |= TIM_IT_CC1;
}


Interrupt handler for TIM3_CH1

void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
 if (TIM3->SR & TIM_SR_CC1IF )
    {

        DataCapture_TIM3 = TIM3->CCR2;
    }

}
```

A problem is HERE for Capturing mode for TIM2_Ch1

```
void TIM2_Config(void)
{ 
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef     TIM_Time_user;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef            port;
    TIM_ICInitTypeDef           TIM_ICInit_user;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure2;
// TIM4 clock enable
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);
// GPIOB clock enable
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
// TIM2 channel_1 configuration : PA0
port.GPIO_Pin   = GPIO_Pin_0;
port.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
port.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;

GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &port);

// Enable the TIM2 global Interrupt
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure2.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure2);

// Time base configuration
TIM_Time_user.TIM_Period = PERIOD;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_Prescaler = PRESCALER;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
TIM_Time_user.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_Time_user);
//
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_Channel = TIM_Channel_1;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICPolarity = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICSelection = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
TIM_ICInit_user.TIM_ICFilter = 0x0;
//
TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM2, &TIM_ICInit_user);
//input trigger
TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM2, TIM_TS_TI1FP1);

  TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM2, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);
    // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
   TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM2,TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
// Enable the TIM2 Counter
TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
// Enable the CC1 Interrupt Request
TIM2->DIER |= TIM_IT_CC1;
}
```

Interrupt handler for TIM2_CH1

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if (TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_CC1IF )
    {

        DataCapture_TIM2 = TIM2->CCR2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I cann't add comment.You can check your setting register values in debug mode and check different between your work and CubeMx setting to find problem

Comment: Thank you for answer I'll try

Comment: Thank you for answer! I checked and all timers are working. Problem was in case of working all timers together/ I didn't solve it yet

Comment: Are you sure about health of hardware?
Is it possible to Interrupt can't handle this?

Comment: For example now dont work tim4. In first place it capture signal but after that it dont change value.(when I turn levers on transmitter) All interrupts are same for 3 timers

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, I recommend you to try [CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html). 
It's a code generator for STM32 that can help you quickly write STM32 low level driver.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I did it in CubeMX, I can show code was generated by Cube and all timers are working (TIM1_CH1, TIM2_CH1, TIM3_CH1, TIM4_CH1), but I can not to fix that problem in SPL

Comment: i'm glad if this could help you or somebody else. You can upvote my answer if you want :)